# Can the legacy PC speaker play two frequencies at the same time?

Tags: assembly, audio, frequency, x86-16

I'm currently working on a piano in x86 assembly. each note translated into frequency and played via the speaker port. I want to be able to play two notes at the same (as one key is pressed and I don't release until after I press another key and the notes "morph" together)

Is it possible?

the playing proc:

```
proc startsound ;push [freq]
    push bp
    mov bp,sp 
    push ax
        ; PORT - connections to computer
        ; ONLY 8 BITS TO PORT
        in al, 61h ; takes value from port 61h to al
        or al, 11b
        out 61h, al ;turns on computer's speaker.
        
        mov al, 0b6h ; constant
        out 43h, al
        
        
        mov ax, [bp+4] ; 1193180/frequency , note
        out 42h, al
        mov al, ah
        out 42h, al
    
    pop ax bp
    ret 4
    endp startsound
```

Comment: See https://habr.com/en/post/439192/ which describes techniques (but doesn't show code) for approximating polyphonic sound out of the IBM PC speaker, e.g. disabling the timer and using it as a DAC.  (Perhaps just a 1-bit DAC that you switch fast enough that the resulting analogue movement of the physical speaker is about right.)  Also other tricks old games used for alternating between two frequencies.

Comment: Highly non-trivial, and a pain in the ass unless you really want to do it as an exercise in retrocomputing.  Modern machines generally have the ability to play back 16-bit PCM samples (like CD-style digital audio) or better; often exposed as a SoundBlaster.  And/or a Midi interface or other queueing of specific samples, e.g. Gravis Ultrasound hardware was popular for mod trackers.  (The audio equivalent of palette-based graphics.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I've seen this done using analog methods. Using a specific speaker as a 1 bit DAC, various patterns are generated and recorded by a microphone to capture the analog movement of the speaker in response to something similar to pulse width modulation. A program is tweaked until sounds recorded by a microphone can be somewhat duplicated on the speaker. I first heard this around 1970 on a CDC 3150, one was a voice recording, the other some song.

Comment: @PeterCordes - in the 1980's a company I worked for did essentially the same thing, sampling patterns and tweaking a program using the speaker as a 1 bit DAC until recording and playback worked reasonably well, then using mag tape to store the DAC bit data stream. This was also done on the Atari ST around 1987 with the game Stargliders, which had some instruments and a vocal group singing the main theme song just after the game was loaded from floppy disk. I recall similar stuff on the PC, but not which titles did this, as sound cards eliminated the need for this. It was noisy, but worked.

Comment: @PeterCordes - WIki has a section about using PCM sound for the [main theme of Starglider on the Atari ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starglider#Audio).

Comment: @rcgldr: hah, nice, I remember what that theme sounded like, at least the main vocal singing the title.  There was a time as a kid when I played quite a bit of Starglider on my (dad's) ST or Mega4 STe.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I still have my Atari ST, brought of storage last year, and copied some floppy based games to new floppy disk. Most of my older double density floppy disks (720K for double sided, 360K for single sided) are still good after 30+ years. The 1.44 MB 3.5 inch floppies don't last anywhere near as long (shallower magnetic fields used on the media).